# basic calculator asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

im having a problem in my ASP .NET calculator project. I'm using VB10, 
all codes are working except for the equals button.
When my input is 1+1, the result will not display in the textbox.I've tried other solution but still does not display the result. Thanks in advance.

Here's my code:

```
Partial Class webcalc
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim total As Double
    Dim total1 As Double
    Dim myOP As String
    Dim sign As Integer
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Protected Sub btn0_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn0.Click
        txtOutput.Text = txtOutput.Text + btn0.Text
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btn1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
        txtOutput.Text = txtOutput.Text + btn1.Text
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btn2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn2.Click
        txtOutput.Text = txtOutput.Text + btn2.Text
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btn3_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn3.Click
        txtOutput.Text = txtOutput.Text + btn3.Text
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btn4_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn4.Click
        txtOutput.Text = txtOutput.Text + btn4.Text
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btn5_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn5.Click
        txtOutput.Text = txtOutput.Text + btn5.Text
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btn6_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn6.Click
        txtOutput.Text = txtOutput.Text + btn6.Text
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btn7_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn7.Click
        txtOutput.Text = txtOutput.Text + btn7.Text
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btn8_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn8.Click
        txtOutput.Text = txtOutput.Text + btn8.Text
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btn9_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn9.Click
        txtOutput.Text = txtOutput.Text + btn9.Text
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btndot_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btndot.Click
        txtOutput.Text = txtOutput.Text + btndot.Text
    End Sub

    '============================================OPERATIONS============================================================

    Protected Sub btnplus_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnplus.Click
        total = Double.Parse(txtOutput.Text)
        txtOutput.Text = " "
        myOP = "+"
        sign = 1

    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnmin_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnmin.Click
        total = Double.Parse(txtOutput.Text)
        txtOutput.Text = " "
        myOP = "-"
        sign = 2

    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnmul_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnmul.Click
        total = Double.Parse(txtOutput.Text)
        txtOutput.Text = " "
        myOP = "*"
        sign = 3

    End Sub

    Protected Sub btndiv_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btndiv.Click
        total = Double.Parse(txtOutput.Text)
        txtOutput.Text = " "
        myOP = "/"
        sign = 4
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btndel_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btndel.Click
        txtOutput.Text = " "
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btneq_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btneq.Click
        Call eq()

    End Sub

    Public Sub eq()
        Select Case myOP

            Case Is = "+"
                total1 = total + Double.Parse(txtOutput.Text)
                'txtOutput.Text = total1.ToString()
                total = 0

            Case Is = "-"
                total1 = total - Double.Parse(txtOutput.Text)
                txtOutput.Text = total1.ToString()
                total = 0

            Case Is = "*"
                total1 = total * Double.Parse(txtOutput.Text)
                txtOutput.Text = total1.ToString()
                total = 0

            Case Is = "/"
                total1 = total / Double.Parse(txtOutput.Text)
                txtOutput.Text = total1.ToString()
                total = 0


        End Select

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be working fine for me if i change your select case like this:

```
myOP = CType(ViewState("myOP"), String)
total = CType(ViewState("total"), Double)

Select Case myOP
        Case "+"
            total1 = total + Double.Parse(txtOutput.Text)
            'txtOutput.Text = total1.ToString()
            total = 0

        Case "-"
            total1 = total - Double.Parse(txtOutput.Text)
            txtOutput.Text = total1.ToString()
            total = 0

        .....
        .....    
End Select
```

and change you operator button click event like this:

```
Protected Sub btnplus_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnplus.Click        
        total = Double.Parse(txtOutput.Text)
        ViewState("total") = total
        txtOutput.Text = " "
        myOP = "+"
        ViewState("myOP") = myOP
        sign = 1

End Sub
```

Comment: ok sir thanks but when i run it the result didn't display in the txtOutput.I'm using google chrome as my browser.

Comment: oh i see why, i tested your code on console.. the reason is when ever post back occurs the value of variables myOP, total reset to default.. Actually you need to save these values in Session or ViewState variable, please have a look at edited answer of mine

Comment: thank you very much sir,it works.now i know that i should save it using the viewstate.thanks again